# Distribution of norms of vectors whose components have a known distribution?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

I know very little of statistics, so forgive me if the question is badly posed.

Suppose I have $n$ samples $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ drawn from some distribution $f$ (let's say $n\approx 100$). Fix $1\leq k \leq n$ (in practice $k \ll n$, say $k\approx 5$). Consider the set

$$
X = \{\lVert (x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, \dotsc, x_{i_k}) \rVert \quad \vert \quad  1\leq i_j \leq n \text{ (distinct)}\},
$$

where $\lVert \cdot\rVert$ is some $L^p$-norm. Can I say anything of the distribution of the members of $X$ (in terms of $n$, $k$, $f$ and $p$, of course)?

Comment: The flippant answer is "yes". But, what are you trying to learn? And, are the components (implicitly) independent here or not? :-)